# Do Americans have their own unique way of referring to 'the summer'?

Tags: idioms, american-english

Across the world *summer* is a season of the year and we all talk about 'the summer' - *do you have plans for the summer ?* etc.

But In America it is often taken to refer to the period of college vacation when students take temporary employment etc. e.g. *She did charity work over the summer*. This would not imply necessarily the climatic summer season, so much as the college vacation.

It is my belief that we do not use *summer* in this way in Britain, unless we say something like *What are you doing over the summer break*?

Can anyone supply further insight into this different nuance which is placed on what is simply a season of the year?

Comment: It can refer to "summer break" when one or both of the speakers is a student. The question "What are you doing this summer?", when posed to a college student, is probably asking about internships or summer employment or possibly additional courses in a summer program or educational travel, not about where the student plans to kick back and relax for a couple of those weeks, on vacation.

Comment: So *summer* only ever refers to astronomical or meteorological summer elsewhere? How sad to live in such a literal-minded place as Not-America sounds like, and how difficult it must be to keep track of when summer begins and ends in each locale. :)

Comment: @TimRomano That is what I meant. But this type of use seems to me to extend to the wider society outside of college students etc. *The summer* seems to have a specific calendar-informed connotation in America, which I have not encountered elsewhere.

Comment: @choster Cheer up for gawd's sake.

Comment: Traditionally, schools shut down in the summer here, but year-round schooling may become a widespread reality in the next 15-20 years.

Comment: I don't think about the time between the end of Spring semester and the start of Fall semester as *a break*.  I think of *breaks* as interruptions *during* a semester.  So Fall Break and Spring Break refer to the week or so off in the middle of the semester.  But school is over after finals in the Spring and does not start up again until the first day of the Fall semseter.  So it's just "summer".

Comment: AFAIK, in the US "*over the summer*" always refers to a time period in the summer, whether or not the context is a break from school. I don't know anyone who would use such an expression to refer to such a school break in the winter, for instance. Can you point to a reference that gave you this idea?

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=q_rNAwAAQBAJ&pg=PP3&dq=%22summer+break%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CHQQ6AEwEWoVChMI4NeQueqNyQIVRj8-Ch2rXQJY#v=onepage&q=%22summer%20break%22&f=false

Comment: @Drew Well you tell me. What do Americans mean when they say *over the summer*? I am trying to get to the bottom of this and understand it. It may have something to do with the fact that your academic year is divided into 2 *semesters*, whilst our is traditionally based on 3 *terms*. But there is definitely a difference in the way people talk of *the summer*. You see our schools and universities have a *summer term* - Autumn term, Spring Term, Summer term. (the latter usually ends in mid-July). So the season of summer is seen to start well before any break arises.

Comment: @Jim I think yours comes closer to answering this than any comment so far. If you read my previous comment to Drew you may see what I am getting at.

Comment: Anyone who thinks this is complicated should try Australia, a country whose cultural references are based around a northern-European climate, but where Christmas falls in the middle of summer.

Comment: @WS2: In America public K-12 schools typically start in early September (about Labor Day) and run until the beginning of June (about Memorial Day). Memorial Day to Labor Day is generally summer vacation from school for all children and college students. The schedule originated when the kids had to be back working on the farm during the summer; now it's just another American quirk. If there are children in the family, what Americans mean is what plans can be made for excursions or vacations as a family. For teens, it usually means jobs or summer school.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks John. That hits the nail on the head. Three months summer break from school - wow. And parents in Britain get driven up the wall by having their kids around the house for 5 weeks! But the length of the break in America clearly determines that specific plans for *the summer* have to be made. And that is exactly the use of the term *summer* which I was trying to get my head around.

Comment: @WS2: Americans mean the same thing as you by "*over the summer*", I think. And American academic years are variable - some schools have quarters; some have semesters; some have 3 periods. There (alas) is no national education system in the US. In the context of school schedules, "*over the summer*" still means over the school break that is more or less during the summer. It's hard to clarify more without some reference to something that you think suggests something different for US usage.

Comment: The answer to the question "*Do Americans have their own unique way of referring to 'the summer'?*" is **no**, AFAICT. You should provide some information about what makes you think the answer might be yes. IOW, why the question?

Comment: @WS2: Not to belabor this, but I'll mention that France too has long [school breaks/vacations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_school_holidays), and there they speak of the summer and winter (and other) "*vacances scolaires*". And there, "*summer*" still has the same meaning as in the US (and I thought as in Britain). But I'm still probably missing something in the question. I'll stop here.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but I think John Lawler has largely cleared this up by reminding me that there is typically a three-month break from school and college. Below is a UK school's typical timetable. The actual break in the summer is no more than about 5 weeks. It is not without problems of its own because it restricts the times when families can take holidays, and prices of hotels, flights etc are driven up exponentially during school holidays. My point being that we do not typically talk of THE SUMMER as a large issue in quite the way you do. But now I better understand why that is.

Comment: http://www.edgbarrowschool.co.uk/parents/useful-information/term-dates/

Comment: @Drew Yes France does have longer holidays. Not only that France as an entire country tends to stop work and go on holiday during the month of August. So it does bear some similarity with the American situation - but the great difference is that French workers often get six or seven weeks holiday. I think this is rather higher than the US average.

Comment: @WS2: Yes, it's **much** longer than the US average. And there is a legal minimum (which I think is 7 weeks now). The US has no legal minimum for vacation time (what you might call holiday time). And even official national holidays (particular days, such as the 4th of July) need not result in time off from work (but they usually do result in time off from public school, at least).

Comment: The US has probably a dozen different climate zones you could identify, and each experiences "summer" in a different way.  In addition, school schedules (both one's own and those of family members), sport "seasons", and job requirements may further delineate what comprises "summer".  I would not expect there to be a single concept or terminology used by the majority of the population.

Comment: Just a clarification.  Since local school districts in the US can decide their own school calendars, some begin summer vacation as early as Memorial Day (late May) and some end as late as Labor Day (early Sept.)  But nowhere is school out for that entire time.  Summer vacation in the US is two months, not three.

Answer (score 2):

In the realm of education, *summer* can indeed refer to the break between the end of the spring term and the beginning of the [fall](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35832/autumn-vs-fall-geographical-distribution-of-usage) term.

Those labels themselves should illustrate, however, that seasons in a particular context need not correspond to their astronomical or meteorological definitions. The *spring semester*, for example, typically begins in January— *[spring break](http://www.theatlantic.com/business/archive/2013/03/2-000-years-of-partying-the-brief-history-and-economics-of-spring-break/274347/)* may well come and go before the vernal equinox. A student who says *I'm taking a Shakespeare course in the spring* to another student will be understood to be referring to the academic term. If the same student said *we're going to go camping in the spring*, it is less clear without additional context whether she means the spring term or to the end of winter. A non-student would no doubt assume the latter.

- For institutions on the semester system (e.g. [University of Texas at Austin](http://registrar.utexas.edu/calendars/15-16)), the spring term typically ends in early- to mid-May, and classes resume for the autumn in mid- to late August.
- For institutions on the quarter system (e.g. [University of California, Los Angeles](http://www.registrar.ucla.edu/calendar/acadcal15.htm)), the spring session typically ends in mid-June, with fall quarter classes beginning in late September.
- Institutions on the trimester system (e.g. [Dartmouth College](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~reg/calendar/academic/15-16.html)) have a similar calendar to the quarter system, but with an abbreviated summer session.

*Summer* is contextual in other seasonally-influenced fields as well. To meteorologists, it [begins at the start of June](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/news/meteorological-versus-astronomical-summer%E2%80%94what%E2%80%99s-difference), not with the solstice. For American workers, it is commonly the period between the Memorial Day holiday in late May to the Labor Day holiday in early September. And for the U.S. Department of Energy, it corresponds to the [driving season](http://www.eia.gov/forecasts/steo/report/summerfuels.cfm) which runs from April to September.

Comment: +1. And I will specifically point out the that for working adult Americans, who are not tied to the school year, summer simply means the season. If I were to ask a coworker "Have any plans over the summer?", I would be inquiring if he's going on vacation sometime during the summer (which in my industry is the slow season).

Comment: @DanBron Unless that working American adult is a teacher, of course :)

Comment: @VampDuc Well, I did qualify it with "who are not tied to the school year" :)

Comment: @DanBron Ah, your comment got broken up weirdly on my device and I missed the line.

Comment: And the comma you used after "adult Americans" made a difference in meaning.